# 2 if-else in one program

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, programming, sensors, bluetooth

Hey guys i have made an automatic plant watering system. Its really basic. the code is:-

```
char yo = 0;
void setup() {
  pinMode(2, INPUT);//moisture sensor
  pinMode(3, OUTPUT);// pump
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  yo = digitalRead(2);
  if(yo == 1){
      digitalWrite(3,HIGH);
      Serial.println("Plant is Being Watered as the soil is dry");
      delay(5000);
    }
  else{
      digitalWrite(3,LOW);
      delay(5000);
      Serial.println("the plant has sufficient water");
    }
}
```

The thing that i want to add is.. i want to add a feature which can manually control it with bluetooth but the normal program should also be running. for eg. soil is wet but i want to add more water so i write 9 on the blueterm app which starts the pump for 2 seconds. I am using an HC-05 bluetooth module. can someone tell me how this can work on an arduino?

EDIT!

Sketch 2:

```
char ha;
void setup() {
  pinMode(3, OUTPUT); //pump
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
 ha = Serial.read();
 if(ha == 5){
    digitalWrite(3, HIGH);
    delay(2000);
  }
 else{
    digitalWrite(3,LOW);
  }
}
```

Comment: How far have you got? Are you able to send data from the app and receive it in your sketch?

Comment: well i have completed both in 2 different sketches that is i can control it manually(send and recieve data from app) in one sketch and run the normal program in the other. when i tried to merge them only the normal program worked and when i entered one in serial nothing happens. @MarkSmith

Comment: Could you add the second sketch to your question, please?

Comment: There @MarkSmith

Comment: You should learn about [finite state machines](https://hackingmajenkoblog.wordpress.com/2016/02/01/the-finite-state-machine/) for this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char ha;
void setup() {
  pinMode(3, OUTPUT); //pump
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() 
{

  //.:.bluetooth control block
  if (Serial.available()) //check serial data availability
  {
    ha = Serial.read();
    if(ha == '9') //received data is char '9'
    {  
      digitalWrite(3, HIGH); //turn on
      delay(2000);
      digitalWrite(3, LOW); //turn off
    }
  } 
  else
  {
    //.:.manual control block
    if(digitalRead(2)){
      digitalWrite(3,HIGH);
      Serial.println("Plant is Being Watered as the soil is dry");
      delay(5000);
      digitalWrite(3,LOW);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: this wont allow the normal program to run(the automatic detection thing)i wanted both to run at the

Comment: @Dhruva you can simply add your former program after it. I edit my answer